# How to concat variable and string in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, concatenation

How to concat variable and string in bash script ?

```
val1 = Variable1 + "any string "
```

eg :

```
val1 = $i + "-i-*"
```

where i = 24thMarch

I want echo val1 :

```
24thMarch-i-*
```

What is proper proper to get the solution ?

Comment: `val1="$i-i-*"` should work. Regarding your first question: `val1="${Variable1}any string"` (note the curlies).

Comment: uuups, just saw that @gniourf already had the same idea as me in my answer.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Strings are concatenated by default in the shell.

```
value="$variable"text"$other_variable"
```

It's generally considered good practice to wrap variable expansions in double quotes.

You can also do this:

```
value="${variable}text${other_variable}"
```

The curly braces are useful when dealing with a mixture of variable names and strings.

Note that there should be no spaces around the `=` in an assignment.

Comment: I didn't mention anything about single quotes. In the second example, the curly braces are needed to separate the variable names with literal text. Granted, the curly braces around the second variable are not needed since the is no ambiguity. The double quotes in the second example _are_ superfluous because there are no spaces but they don't do any harm.

Answer (score 3):

Nice.

Mac OS X 10.12 works with following ...

---

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=bar
var2=foo
var3="$var1"sometext
echo $var3
```

---

Result

```
barsometext
```

Comment: Where does the value from `var2` ("foo") in the result come from?

Comment: Result should be modify. Actual result is `barsometext`

Comment: No, `var2` has no impact to the result (`var3`) that is outputted and can hereby removed from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Late for the party, my 2 cents for another solu., also works in `zsh`:

```
i=`date +%d%b`
```

`val1="$i-i-*"`

Comment: @LogicalBranch I rolled back your edit; it introduced errors.

Comment: @PeterPanX Ditto; your "typo fixes" broke perfectly good, valid code.

Comment: @tripleee Ah! Hadn't realised, thanks for the heads up.