# how to check the directory size using find command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a requirement of finding the directory size which is more than a particular value and I made a script for the same. But find command is not accepting -size section. Can anyone help me on this

```
echo -e "This script will generate report for directories which consumes more size than the given value"
read -p " Enter the file system or directory full path: " path
read -p " This script will check the directories which is greater than the given size Please Enter the directory size in GB: " size
find $path  -type d -size +$sizeG -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

error

```
find: invalid -size type `+'
```

Comment: Your command looks for a variable named `sizeG`; you want `${size}G`, or `"$size"G`, or `"${size}G"`.

Comment: `-size` on directories probably doesn't work as you expect. It doesn't count the size of the files inside the directory. You probably need to use `du $path` instead and filter out the directories you want.

Comment: I reopened as "not a duplicate" because fixing the variable name error doesn't result in what you want, as per @TedLyngmo's comment.

Comment: Other duplicate candidate: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16661982/3266847); see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32696871/3266847) for the syntax problem you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check folder size in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661982/check-folder-size-in-bash)

Comment: I tried all these option but no of these options are working.

Comment: Let me check. 
My actual requirement is to print the directory, which has size more than some value. This script has to execute on the storage volume, which has 1 TB size. I guess du will take long time to get the result. That is the reason I tried find.

Comment: Use `df` instead of `du` if you want the size of an entire volume.

Comment: I tried it but not working. 
To narrow down the issue, I tried to execute find command alone and found it is not giving result if we use -type d. 
find  /root -size +10M -type d  -exec ls -ld {} \;
The same command is working if we use type f. anyone have knows how it can be done for directories ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to eliminate bad substitution error in bash script. Wrap the variable size with a double quota.

```
    echo -e "This script will generate report for directories which consumes more size than the given value"

read -p " Enter the file system or directory full path: " path
read -p " This script will check the directories which is greater than the given size Please Enter the directory size in GB: " size

echo "+${size}G";

find $path  -type d -size "+${size}G" -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

Comment: I tried it but not working. 
To narrow down the issue, I tried to execute find command alone and found it is not giving result if we use -type d.
find  /root -size +10M -type d  -exec ls -ld {} \;

Comment: if you are getting permission denied error. Try with Sudo privilege.

Comment: Sample from ubuntu: fatihsennik@fatihsennik:~$ find /  -type d -size +10G -exec ls -ld {} \;
find: ‘/etc/polkit-1/localauthority’: Permission denied

Comment: No. It is not permission denied error. output will not get id we use type but we will get the result if we use type f